# what is difference between POST Method from Client Side html and Server Side C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

html Post Method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitdata() {
        document.tp_form.submit();
    }
</script>

<form name="tp_form" action="someurl" method="post" id="form_id">
<table>
<tr>
//// In td i send all the same parameter as which send from C# 
<td>User ID : <input type="text" name="user_id" value="test"><br></td>
<td>Order No : <input type="text" name="order_no" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" name="hash" value="hash" onClick="submitdata();" > </td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

C# Post Method

```
NameValueCollection collections = new NameValueCollection();
            collections.Add("user_id", api3.user_id);
            collections.Add("order_no", api3.order_no);
            collections.Add("pay_type", api3.pay_type);
            collections.Add("good_name", api3.good_name);
            collections.Add("trade_mony", api3.trade_mony);
            collections.Add("order_first_name", api3.order_first_name);
            collections.Add("order_email", api3.order_email);
            collections.Add("currency", api3.currency);
            collections.Add("site_cd", api3.site_cd);
            collections.Add("hash_data", api3.hash_data);


            string html = "<html><head>";
            html += "</head><body onload='document.forms[0].submit()'>";
            html += string.Format("<form name='PostForm' method='POST' action='{0}'>", apiurl);
            foreach (string key in collections.Keys)
            {
                html += string.Format("<input name='{0}' type='hidden' value='{1}'>", key, collections[key]);
            }
            html += "</form></body></html>";
            Response.Clear();

            Response.Write(html);
```

When I do Post From HTML it is redirected to Payment Page But when I am doing from C# it is not redirecting it is giving me error.In Both case parameters are same.

What is the difference in both way i.e HTML and C#

Comment: Can you give us more detail on the Error? Your Server is actually not performing any POST. You're just rendering HTML Code to output in the Response, using the JavaScript in the body to perform the actual submit.

Comment: This is not a C#/HTML issue. this is pure HTML. you are just rendering the html from C#. Check the source of the HTML that was generated by C#. The problem is there. also the html you've posted is not the same as the html that you generate using C#.

Comment: What is the error?